# Forbit CORS request in node.js

Tags: node.js, cors

I have a nodejs Express app which serves a static front-end app. I have an endpoint that I'd like to prevent the access from all the others domains.

One solution could be using CRSF but I'd prefer avoiding this. Is there a simple way?

My app is very simple:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/dist')));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.post('/endpoint', (req, res) => {
    res.send();
});
app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8080);
```

Comment: The browser is usually required to send `Host: <domain>` header when requesting a resource. You could fetch that header in the `request` object and block all requests that do not have the domain you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Does the domain have a static IP? You could add your domains IP to a whitelist blocking access to your endpoint from all IP's bar your own:

[express-ipfilter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-ipfilter)

If you don't have a static IP so that you can block requests you could start by configuring CORS with the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header set to your domain. This will block cross origin access from the browser but isn't a complete fix for what you want.

[Configuring CORS](https://github.com/expressjs/cors#configuring-cors)

Comment: Nope it's a dynamic one

Comment: I updated my answer with another idea, sorry if it's no help for you.